# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'provider' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `oauth_clients`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Am using Laravel version 8 and I am trying to run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed & php artisan passport:install`

The migrations and seeding successfully run but `php artisan passport:install` fails

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'provider' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `oauth_clients` (`user_id`, `name`, `secret`, `provider`, `redirect`, `personal_access_client`, `password_client`, `revoked`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Laravel Personal Access Client, Wa44O2Z3IA23st3wbgQHvDkapJlS75ZXO7MZ4A4Q, ?, http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 2021-02-11 15:09:29, 2021-02-11 15:09:29))

Basically while trying to insert the token a column `provider` is not found and on checking my oauth_clients_table  migration file is see that the column `provider` is actually missing

```php
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('secret', 100)->nullable();
            $table->text('redirect');
            $table->boolean('personal_access_client');
            $table->boolean('password_client');
            $table->boolean('revoked');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I seem not to find this information about the column, My questions is since this migrations were generated automatically, before I upgraded my application, what is the structure of this column?

**EDIT 1**
I have tried below and it failed

```
$table->string('provider');
```

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'provider' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `oauth_clients` (`user_id`, `name`, `secret`, `provider`, `redirect`, `personal_access_client`, `password_client`, `revoked`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Laravel Personal Access Client, GiZ5BQgqtbbvCuIupO3bhMZHLK0YlIq22LvjWGGG, ?, http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 2021-02-11 15:33:28, 2021-02-11 15:33:28))

So I added

```
$table->string('provider')->nullable('web');
```

The above works but now my question is

1. Is the above correct?
2. What is the purpose of the `provider` column in `oauth_clients` table?

Comment: Did you upgraded laravel framework or passport? Please check [this](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/1264#issuecomment-746724846) thread

Comment: Thanks @porloscerrosΨ The link was totally helpful

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the Upgrade.md file it mentions:

> ### Upgrading To 9.0 From 8.x
>
> #### Support For Multiple Guards
>
> PR: https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1220
>
> Passport now has support for multiple guard user providers. Because of
> this change, you must add a `provider` column to the `oauth_clients`
> database table:
>
> ```
> Schema::table('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
>     $table->string('provider')->after('secret')->nullable();
> });
> ```
>
> If you have not previously published the Passport migrations, you
> should manually add the `provider` column to your database.

So I just added the following migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddProviderColumnToOauthClientsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('provider')->after('secret')->nullable();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('provider');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be updated to check for the existence of the `provider` column before adding it. Since the existing migration was updated this will fail if you deploy to a new system with a fresh db since the Laravel migration will have already added it.